# Fetch.Join() not working in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following mapping override on one side of the relationship:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<ItemAsmtDetailDh> mapping)
{
    mapping.HasMany<WAsmtDetail>(x => x.WAsmtDetails).Inverse().AsBag().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Access.PascalCaseField(Prefix.Underscore).Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join();
}
```

and on the other side of the relationship I have:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<WAsmtDetail> mapping)
{
    mapping.References<ItemAsmtDetailDh>(x => x.ItemAsmtDetailDh).Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join();
}
```

When I use the ShowSql option I see that it's still issuing separate select statements for the WAsmtDetails giving me the dreaded "n + 1 selects" problem.  Why is ".Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join()" being ignored?

Note:  I'm using Fluent NHibernate version 1.1, ***not*** version 2.1, because of a bug in the newer version.  (See my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085456/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-of-a-bi-directional-many-to-many-association-using-an) for bug details.)  I'm using NHibernate version 2.1.2.4000.

Answer (score 7):

You are most likely loading the data in a way that isn't affected by `Fetch.Join()` in the mapping (like HQL or Linq). From the NHibernate documentation:

> The fetch strategy defined in the mapping document affects:
>
> - retrieval via Get() or Load()
> - retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated
> - ICriteria queries
> - HQL queries if subselect fetching is used

Comment: Thanks for the reply, cremor.  In my situation, I use CreateCriteria to retrieve a list of objects at the aggregate root level.  The aggregate root is 2 levels above the "ItemAsmtDetailDh" class mentioned in my question.  I then delete the parent of ItemAsmtDetailDh (1 level up).  NH is retrieving the rest of the aggregate from that point downward in order to delete it.  I would consider this a case of retrieval by navigation of associations.